# OPA policy is working in policy playground but failing in cluster

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

team!

I have created a policy for Nginx ingress annotation and I have tested it with the Rego playground (https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/EEOfeSQHFo). Is not showing any error in the playground but when I deploy it in the cluster it is not working as expected.

**Expected result:**

When deploying the ingress manifest file, it should contain the annotation limit-connections and the value should be 5 or 10 or it should return the error.

Can somebody please review my rego code?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your policy. The Kubernetes API server however expects the response to be formatted as an [AdmissionReview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#response) object. The OPA docs on Kubernetes provides an [example](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-primer/#detailed-admission-control-flow) of how you may create one.

Comment: Does it mean I need to create a k8s "AdmissionReview" resource? as mentioned in the OPA document?

Comment: If you're using Gatekeeper, that will do this for you, but if using plain OPA, then yes.

Comment: Yes, I have installed Gatekeeper in another namespace